# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2754 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

**Table**

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE project (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    content TEXT,
    postdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
")

te = "testing"
c.execute("INSERT INTO project (content) values (?)", (te))
```

**Error**

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.
    The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.
```

Comment: which is it? 2754 are supplied or 7 are supplied?  why are your error messages between your title and question different?

Answer (score 4):

Try to change it into:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO project (content) values (?)", (te,))
```

(with the comma after the te). This is because `(te)` without the comma is not a tuple, and you have to pass the parameters in a tuple. If you only have one element, you have to tell python that it is a tuple by inserting a final comma.

Comment: Or change it into a list.